# Match length of index to length of list in loop

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a DataFrame that I want to expand with the expansion of a list.

```
df['IPS'] = pd.Series(ip)
df[date] = pd.Series(countfreq(re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', str(
print (df)
```

The list `ip` expands but when setting the column it doesn't show the new elements. It keeps the same length that was first passed in (19)

```
0    127.15.20.191           2
1     64.255.65.13           2
2   175.248.78.182           2
3     37.83.22.114           1
4    33.68.135.110           2
5   101.124.127.56           2
6    236.32.91.121           2
7   207.229.230.76           2
8    90.16.136.130           2
9     64.199.43.58           2
10   127.15.20.191           2
11    64.255.65.13           2
12  175.248.78.182           2
13   33.68.135.110           2
14  101.124.127.56           2
15   236.32.91.121           2
16  207.229.230.76           2
17   90.16.136.130           2
18    64.199.43.58           2
```

For example if the length of the list was changed to 20

```
0    127.15.20.191           2
1     64.255.65.13           2
2   175.248.78.182           2
3     37.83.22.114           1
4    33.68.135.110           2
5   101.124.127.56           2
6    236.32.91.121           2
7   207.229.230.76           2
8    90.16.136.130           2
9     64.199.43.58           2
10   127.15.20.191           2
11    64.255.65.13           2
12  175.248.78.182           2
13   33.68.135.110           2
14  101.124.127.56           2
15   236.32.91.121           2
16  207.229.230.76           2
17   90.16.136.130           2
18    64.199.43.58           2
19    64.210.89.88           1
```

Comment: I'm not certain but I think you want `df.IPS.map(df.IPS.value_counts())`.  That is one of many ways to accomplish what I **think** you want.  `df.groupby('IPS').IPS.transform('size')` or `(lambda s: np.bincount(s)[s])(df.IPS.factorize()[0])`

Comment: the question seems to be incomplete, can you provide sample data?

Comment: @Yuca Just a list of random IPs

Comment: if so, provide one :) that way is easier to help you

Comment: @piRSquared doesn't seem to work. The program will constantly scan text for IPS and in the `ip` list it will add the new ones it has found. I need it to add those new IPS to the end of the IPS column (new rows) with their appropriate values